# Java: Checking if an IP address is in an Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there a particular way to check if an IP address does NOT exist in an arrayList? Right now i have an arraylist that is made up of strings of IP Addresses (e.g. "192.168.0.4", etc.). After receiving a packet i'd like to check if the packet's IP address belongs in the arraylist.

At first i thought something like this would suffice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
{
  if (packet.getAddress().equals(InetAddress.getByName(myList.get(i))))
  {
    System.out.println("this packet's IP address is in list");
  }

  else
  {
    System.out.println("this packet's IP address is not in list!");
  }
```

I thought the else statement would solve this situation but i was wrong. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for [`ArrayList#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))?

Comment: If you plan to do a lot of lookups, use a `HashSet` instead. This will greatly speed up things, especially if you have a lot of IP addresses.

Comment: Use a hash based collection for faster search

Comment: If you can use Set in your design, the add() method returns boolean based on whether value was already in the set.

Comment: ooo i'll definitely look into HashSet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the entire list before you know the IP is not there :

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size() && !found; i++) {
    if (packet.getAddress().equals(InetAddress.getByName(myList.get(i)))) {
        found = true;
        System.out.println("this packet's IP address is in list");
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("this packet's IP address is not in list!");
}
```

Comment: Why not just `break` when ip is found?. After setting boolean flag :)

Comment: @TheLostMind That will work too. But if you use break, you still need the flag in order to know if the IP was found (unless you are going to rely on the value of i, which is less readable).

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to convert the ArrayList to a Set (not before every check as it would be unnecessary overhead), this way you can avoid the for loop. It is just a matter of

```
Set<InetAddress> mySet = new HashSet<InetAddress>(myList);
...
if(mySet.contains(packet.getAddress())) {
 // ...
}
```

I think you may also use myList.contains, but I think that the implementation loops through the list anyway, so using a Set would be faster.

Comment: i think that's a good idea. Always good to have things faster

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're printing the message for each item that doesn't match the address. Instead, you could encapsulate this functionality in a method, return a boolean value and then do the printing:

```
public boolean isPackedInList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        if (packet.getAddress().equals(InetAddress.getByName(myList.get(i)))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then use it:

```
if (isPackedInList()) {
    System.out.println("this packet's IP address is in list");
} else {
    System.out.println("this packet's IP address is not in list!");
}
```